# Java property file with different extension

Tags: java

I know its a bad question, but just wanted to know. We have property files (.properties) in java, where we can read and write using Java.util.Properties class. I am able to use the same Java.util.Properties class to read and write file with different extension like .dat , .ini which has key-value pair. Do we have any potential difference when .dat or .ini file is read using Java.util.Properties when compared to having file as .properties.

Comment: No nothing as long as key-value pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't find the question stupid at all.

No, loading properties from a File [via `Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) or [via `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) does not care what the name of the underlying file is (in fact there doesn't have to be an underlying File at all).

The only difference is that only .properties files are picked up automatically by the [`PropertyResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make use of other extensions too like .date or .ini.

But to maintain coding standards, Its highly recommended that you go for a .properties file!!

`As the extension says clearly, these are described as Property Resource Bundles. So use .properties for naming convention purpose and easier maintainability.`